# EditText theme in custom themed dialog

Tags: android, themes

I have created a simple custom theme for my dialog boxes, but now the EditText elements inside the Dialogs that use this theme do not keep the nice default ICS theme.

Here is the theme I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="DarkDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/DarkDialogTitle</item>
    <item name="android:background">#282828</item>
</style>
<style name="DarkDialogTitle">
    <item name="android:textColor">#33B5E5</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
     <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
</style>
```

And this is what I see when I use it:

[image]

Is there a way to make the EditText elements inside my custom themed Dialogs use the default theme for whatever device they are on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need a theme for each api level you want to control.

For API values less than 11, base your style on `@android:style/Theme`

between 11 and 13 `@android:style/Theme.Holo`

and for 14 and higher `@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault`

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to derive from the Holo dialog theme:

```
<style name="DarkDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
```